# edit via function php the gallery in posts created with gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to modify the html output of the gallery that is provided by gutemberg via function php ... but I can't.

How do you intercept and modify yourself?

this is the original:

```
<ul="wp-block-gallery columns-2 is-cropped">
  <li class="blocks-gallery-item">....</li>
  <li class="blocks-gallery-item">....</li>
</ul>
```

and I would like to change it based on the number of columns to adapt it to my development framework ...

```
<div class="grid-x">
   <div class="box-50">...</div>
   <div class="box-50">...</div>
</div>
```

exists how to change it via function.php ??

Comment: Did you check if filter exists in wordpress for that ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not understanding anything because they juggle js and php and I lose myself all the time ... It would be nice to just recover the values ​​in php and make the change with a replace.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298225/how-to-extend-the-gallery-block-in-gutenberg

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Exemple of Wp gutenberg html output override via function php:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', 'GutenGallery' , 10, 2 );

  function GutenGallery( $block_content, $block )
  {

    if ( 'core/gallery' !== $block['blockName'] || ! isset( $block['attrs']['ids'] ) )
    {
      return $block_content;
    }

    $li = '';
    $col = $block['attrs']['columns'];

    foreach( (array) $block['attrs']['ids'] as $id ) {

      if( $col == "1" || !$col)
      {
        $li .= sprintf( '<div class="box-[50-50-100]"><div class="autocrop radius-medium" style="height:300px;">%s</div></div>', wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'large' ) );
      }
      elseif ($col == "2" )
      {
        $li .= sprintf( '<div class="box-[50-50-100]"><div class="autocrop radius-medium" style="height:300px;">%s</div></div>', wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'large' ) );
      }
      elseif ($col == "3" )
      {
        $li .= sprintf( '<div class="box-[33-33-100]"><div class="autocrop radius-medium" style="height:300px;">%s</div></div>', wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'large' ) );
      }
      elseif ($col >= "4" )
      {
        $li .= sprintf( '<div class="box-[25-25-50]"><div class="autocrop radius-medium" style="height:300px;">%s</div></div>', wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'large' ) );
      }

    }
    return sprintf( '<div class="grid-x gap-20">%s</div>', $li );

  }
```

(box are the grid in use on my framewok [kimera](https://github.com/ShapeGroup/kimera-frontend-framework))

thank you all ;)