# Get content layouts of grid into gutenber blog

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Based on the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402138/edit-via-function-php-the-gallery-in-posts-created-with-gutenberg) development I built a small code to modify the gutenber grids. However I don't know how to retrieve the contents of the columns and reapply it to the context.

Into funciton.php

```
  // Change WordPress gutenberg grid
  add_filter( 'render_block', 'GutenGrid' , 10, 2 );
  function GutenGrid( $block_content, $block )
  {

    if ( $block['blockName'] !== 'core/columns' )
    {
      return $block_content;
    }

    $col = $block['attrs']['columns'];

    $boxes = '';

    // foreach( (array) $block['attrs']['ids'] as $id ) {
    for ($c = 0; $c <= $col-1; $c++) {


     if ($col == "3" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[33-33-100]"><div><p>type3col</p>'. content ?? .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col == "4" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[25-25-50]"><div><p>type4col</p>'. content ?? .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col == "5" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[20-20-50]"><div><p>type5col</p>'. content ?? .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col >= "6" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[15-15-50]"><div><p>type6col</p>'. content ?? .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      else {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[50-50-100]"><div><p>type1&2col</p>'. content ?? .'</div></div>' ;
      }

    }

    $output = '<p>GRID REWRITED:</p><div class="grid-x gap-30">'.$boxes.'</div>';

    return sprintf( $output, $boxes );

  }
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

```
      // Change WordPress gutenberg grid
  add_filter( 'render_block', 'GutenGrid' , 10, 2 );
  function GutenGrid( $block_content, $block )
  {

    if ( $block['blockName'] !== 'core/columns' )
    {
      return $block_content;
    }

    $col = $block['attrs']['columns'];
    $content = $block['innerBlocks'][0]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'];

    $boxes = '';

    // foreach( (array) $block['attrs']['ids'] as $id ) {
    for ($c = 0; $c <= $col-1; $c++) {


     if ($col == "3" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[33-33-100]"><div>'. $block['innerBlocks'][$c]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'][0] .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col == "4" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[25-25-50]"><div>'. $block['innerBlocks'][$c]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'][0] .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col == "5" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[20-20-50]"><div>'. $block['innerBlocks'][$c]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'][0] .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      elseif ($col >= "6" )
      {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[15-15-50]"><div>'. $block['innerBlocks'][$c]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'][0] .'</div></div>' ;
      }
      else {
        $boxes .= '<div class="box-[50-50-100]"><div>'. $block['innerBlocks'][$c]['innerBlocks'][0]['innerContent'][0] .'</div></div>' ;
      }

    }

    $output = '<p>GRID REWRITED:</p><div class="grid-x gap-30">'.$boxes.'</div>';

    return sprintf( $output, $boxes );

  }
```